# Retrieve million records from MySQL Table in Map using Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, dictionary

I have the following issue:
I have one application that stores some files, and for each file creates 2 entries in a MySQL table: the path to the file, and one value X (unique identifierthat can be found in the file).

The same Unique identifier value is also stored in the File itself.

Now I have written a little program as we are having some inconsistencies because some files have the same path as in the DB Table, but a different Value X in the file itself (the value in the file is the correct one).

I have written a Java application that:
first reads all files (using DCM4CHEE library), stores the Path to the file and the Value X in a map object(using the path as a key). 
Then reads the MySQL table using a query, stores the retrieved values (path + Value X) in another map, and finally compares the 2 maps and writes the inconsistent records to a file.

Unfortunately there are cases where we have over 2-3 millions files to read (and records in the MySQL table), and this makes the retrieval very slow.
The files need to be read individually (as they are medical records written using a special file format (DICOM)  and I need a special library to access the content.

**My questions are:** 
1 - is using Maps to store over 3 millions records appropriate in Java or shall I use a different Object? Is there something more efficient?

2 - to retrieve the records from MySQL I launch a series of query limited on the number of records (from record 1 to x, elaborate the results, then again from x to y, elaborate, and so on (y to z...) until all records have been read. I do this as a single query to retrieve all records is taking extremely long. 
Is what I am doing correct? Is there a better way to do this in Java?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Would storing the file to the database solve the problem?  I mean store a path to a file is a bit of an anti pattern as you have to manage those paths if the files are moved etc.

Comment: Using Maps can be a correct way to store 3m+ records, depending on each record size. For the second part you can also look into caching the records that can be used in merge queries. It also depends on how you are expensive your queries are. Your question is too broad to provide one correct answer, try to be specific

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - is using Maps to store over 3 millions records appropriate in Java or shall I use a different Object? Is there something more efficient?

Maps should be fine, as long as you have enough available memory in your process space to hold the data. If each entry is 100 bytes on average (sounds about right for a path plus key?), you would need up to 300MB. If each entry is 500 bytes, you're looking at 1.5GB.

> 2 - to retrieve the records from MySQL I launch a series of query limited on the number of records (from record 1 to x, elaborate the results, then again from x to y, elaborate, and so on (y to z...) until all records have been read. I do this as a single query to retrieve all records is taking extremely long.

There should generally not be a problem reading all records in a single query (although if you ORDER BY, that could become relatively expensive under some circumstances). 2-3 million records is not much at all for a MySQL system with appropriate hardware and a proper configuration.

Some things to check:

- Is your MySQL server appropriately configured? The default configuration file is *not* a good starting point.
- Do you have an index on any fields that are part of a WHERE or ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Hello thank you for your suggestions. You are right, the size of the memory used is between 1.5 and 2Gb. 
I cannot change the MySQL configuration file (unfortunately) as this is not managed by me. I cannot use a where clause as I need to retrieve all records out of the table (i only limit the number of column ), this is why I started using batch of queries and the "limit" option in my query: "SELECT s.`ID`, s.`SOPINSTANCEUID`, s.STORAGE_ID, s.`PATHINSTORAGE`, s.`SERIES_ID` FROM sopinstance s limit x, y;" (x starting of the batch, y being the end).

Answer (score 0):

You should invert your approach and write new correct data into MySQL. Either in a new table/column or directly update the wrong data. This way you won't have to bother with your both questions. Anything that can be done in SQL should be done in SQL.

Correction: If the files content has to be updated and the original table may not, then it's hard to say what approach will be faster. But that mostly because it's not clear how efficient can you interface your DB in your environment with your skillset.

Still it may be faster and easier if you can collect files content and paths into a csv list, upload it to DB, do a join on path and non-matching content to the original table, extract the resulting records and update files in a loop.

Bulk uploads and downloads are very fast with MySQL and processing files in the loop does not tax memory.

Comment: Let me first of all thank you all for your answers / ideas, it is always good to hear different opinions and share experiences with experienced developers!
I can not change the content of the MySQL Table as it is the correct content, I can only read the correct content, and later on I will have to modify the File content (DICOM Header). If I would use a new Table for the manipulation (instead of Maps) out of your experience do you think my program would offer a better performance?